# Displaying PHP Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php

Hi everyone im new at php so here is my code i am having trouble displaying php in many to many relationship im doing a student information system

here is my database

**student**

student_id

name

address

course

**subject**

subject_id

subject_name

subject_code

**student_subject**

subject_id

student_id

Here is my query

```
$sql = "SELECT subject_name
        FROM   subject
             LEFT JOIN student_subject ON (student.student_id = 'student_id')
                    LEFT JOIN subject ON (subject.subject_id = 'subject_id' )";

$records = mysql_query($sql);
```

and now this is my code to display it please help me how to display this example i just only want to display the subject name and the subject code

```
while($student=mysql_fetch_array($records)){

      echo $student['subject_name'];
      echo $student['subject_code'];
}
```

this is only sample because this is only what i want to dispaly please help me thanks sorry for my bad english. cant search anything about displaying many to many relationship in google i can see some query but i cant search about the code i tried many but i always failed thank you so much

desired Output:

Subject Name  ---|---  Subject CODE
ICT___________||_________IT 101
 
ALGEBRA_______||_________ MATH101

remove the underscore in your vision cant fix the output new here in stackoverflow

Comment: If you want to show subjects per student, you need to select from student_select finding by student_id,  and you need to select the subject_name.

Comment: Please let us know what you would like to display?

Comment: Please add some example of the desired output

Comment: Also note that the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated as of 5.5, and are removed in 7.0. Use mysqli, or PDO instead.

Comment: i want to display the corresponding subject to the student_id that take by the student example the student take computerclass and mathclass  

student 10002 take the math and computer i want to display the computer and math class ? how can i do that thank you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('There is an error to connect DB' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('test') or die ('Unable to select DB' . mysql_error());

$query = 'SELECT ST.student_id, ST.name, ST.address, SB.subject_name, SB.subject_code FROM student ST, subject SB, `student_subject` STSB WHERE STSB.student_id=ST.student_id AND STSB.subject_id=SB.subject_id';

$query = mysql_query($query) or die('Unable to execute query' . mysql_error());

if ($query) {
    $str = '';
    $header = '<tr><td>Student ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Subject</td><td>Subject Code</td></tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $str .= '<tr>';
        $student_id = $row['student_id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $subject = $row['subject_name'];
        $subject_code = $row['subject_code'];

        $str .= '<td>' . $student_id . '</td>';
        $str .= '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
        $str .= '<td>' . $address . '</td>';
        $str .= '<td>' . $subject . '</td>';
        $str .= '<td>' . $subject_code . '</td>';
        $str .= '</tr>';
    }
    if ($str) {
        $table = '<table border="1">' . $header      . $str . '</table>';
    } else {
        $tdata = '<tr><td colspan="5">No data found</td></tr>';
        $table = '<table border="1">' . $header . $tdata . '</table>';
    }
    echo $table;
}
```

Output will be like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)  where do you get the ST on your query ?

Comment: is that the table name ?? or the database name ?

Comment: ST is an alias defined for student table in FROM sql clause like 'FROM student ST'. You can define an alias for a property like a table so you can refer it quickly and briefly without rewrite the whole table name.
Example: 
STSB.student_id = ST.student_id **is shortest then*
student_subject.student_id = student.student_id